# Keyboard shortcuts do not work inside Windows Sandbox

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sandbox, windows-sandbox

I have noticed a strange effect inside full-screen Windows Sandbox sessions: if I use a keyboard shortcut like `WINKEY + I`, this ignores the Sandbox and opens Settings on the host OS. This is strange because if I have a Remote Desktop Connection open to another Windows system, and I am full screen there, `WINKEY + I` will properly act on the remote system and not the host OS.

Note that this problem is specifically for Windows 10 (comment below states that it works as expected on Windows 11). Is there some way to get keyboard shortcut keys to act on the Windows 10 Sandbox intuitively so that any key combo pressed inside the Sandbox will act on the Sandbox and not on the host OS?

Comment: The WinKey + I key works correctly on my installation of Sandbox. Windows 11 Pro and then Sandbox.  What version of Windows are you using?  Make very sure you click inside the Sandbox for the shortcut to work

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 and I've done a full Reset of the system, still no help. I make sure that I'm inside the Sandbox and this problem also is happening when the Sandbox is Full Screen sadly.

Comment: It may have been a correction on Windows 11

Comment: Indeed, could be. Don't have a system that can run Windows 11 unfortunately. I'll update the question with the OS; thanks for noting that this works on Windows 11.

Comment: @YorSubs - Are you sure? Windows 11  sensationally has the same processor and memory, while they have soft blocked older processors for a variety of reasons, most of those processors can still run Windows 11 without a problem.  In other words, if your system runs Windows 10, it's very likely it will have zero problems running Windows 11.  You might not be able to enable one of a select few features linked directly to the processor requirements (basically fTPM), but you are not using those features on Windows 10, so you wouldn't be losing anything.

Comment: Agree, but I'd need to completely reformat my disk as GPT and set SecureBoot (can't work around those requirements I think).